# How to apply css only for first span

Tags: css

Trying to apply CSS

```css
.content>span:first-child{
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="content">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <use xlink:href="assets/icons.svg#back-button"></use>
    </svg>
     <span> Lorem ipsom </span>
<!-- only this span font color should be red -->

<span>
       <span> </span>
</span>
</span>
```

for only the first span. I have tried but it is not working. If anyone knows please help to find the solution.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-use-gvmekn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first-of-type so something like:

```
.content > span:first-of-type {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## use the :first-of-type pseudo-class

> `:first-of-type`
>
> The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

```css
span.content > span:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="content">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="0" stroke="black" />
</svg>

  <span> Lorem ipsom </span>
  <!-- only this span font color should be red -->

  <span>
    Child
   <span> Inner child </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

## use adjacent sibling combinator

> `+`
>
> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

```css
svg+span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="content">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="0" stroke="black" />
</svg>

  <span> Lorem ipsom </span>
  <!-- only this span font color should be red -->

  <span>
    Child
   <span> Inner child </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `:first-child` selector only applies if the `span` you're after is the first child of `.content`.

In your case the first child is an `svg` tag, hence why it's not working.

There are 3 ways of getting around this:

1. Make the selector `.content > span:nth-child(2)`. This'll work in the above but will again break if you ever put additional elements between the span in question and your svg.
2. `.content > span:first-of-type`. This seems to be what you're after, i.e. the first span that's the child of `.content`.
3. `span.some-meaningful-classname` - This gives you the flexibility to choose exactly which spans to apply the class to by adding `classname="some-meaningful-classname"` to your span.

Up to you which to go with, depending on your requirements.

Also, there's a good reference to CSS selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by just giving the span a class like the following

Old:

```
<span> Lorem ipsom </span>
```

New:

```
<span class="firstspan"> Lorem ipsom </span>
```

(Edit: Sorry forgot to mark the  as code so it did not display correctly)

next you can add the class name to the css file like this:

```
.firstspan {
  /* this is a example of code that will make the text red*/
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Because the `.container` is also a span, the declarations overlap each other.**

---

To do this, you just need to target the nth child, like `span:nth-child(2)` or whichever span you want by nth-child('child No.'). Here is the solution:

---

HTML:

```
<span class="content">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <use xlink:href="assets/icons.svg#back-button"></use>
      </svg>
      <span> Lorem ipsom </span>
      <!-- only this span font color should be red -->

      <span>
        <span> </span>
      </span>
    </span>
```

CSS:

```
span:nth-child(2) {
        color: red;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
```